# Installing the Pantheon desktop/ElementaryOS theme on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: 20.10, elementary, pantheon

The recommended way seems to involve adding a a repository `ppa:elementary-os/daily`, which doesn't work for 20.10. Can anyone recommend a way to install this on Ubuntu 20.10?

Comment: The Pantheon desktop is made by the ElementaryOS team and for ElementaryOS. Because that OS is based on Ubuntu LTS releases its PPA doesn't support interim releases.